# Reading only first value out of each JSON object

Tags: c#, json

I'm sending over 120 requests (between multiple tasks) to
[this API](https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items?ids=24,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,123,125,126,128,129,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,236,237,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272) (200 objects) and my goal is to only get the names without even touching the rest.

```
public async Task<List<string>> ZwrocNazwe(string zapytanie)
        {
            var listaNazw = new List<string>();

            var s = await _klientHttp.GetStreamAsync(zapytanie);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
            using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            {
                reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject) continue;
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.Value.ToString() != "name") continue;
                    reader.Read();
                    listaNazw.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.Value));
                    reader.Skip();
                }
            }
            return listaNazw;
        }
```

I works, but takes more time than I expected it would. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the function that combines results:

```
    public async Task<List<string>> ZwrocListePrzedmiotow(List<int> listaId, string sciezka)
    {
        // Groups ids of items into groups of 200. 
        var listaZapytan = ZwrocListeZapytan(listaId);

        // Makes request per each group to get item info.
        var listaZadan = new List<Task<List<string>>>();
        foreach (var zapytanie in listaZapytan)
            listaZadan.Add(
                ZwrocNazwe(sciezka + zapytanie));

        // Combines results.
        await Task.WhenAll(listaZadan);
        var listaPrzedmiotow = new List<string>();
        foreach (var zadanie in listaZadan)
            listaPrzedmiotow.AddRange(zadanie.Result);

        return listaPrzedmiotow;
    }
```

Funny thing is that since I started using `GetStreamAsync` instead of `GetStringAsync` I'm waiting even longer for the results.

Comment: "takes more time than I expected it would". This is rather vague to say the least. What were your expectations, and what is the time you're experiencing? Is is the HTTP request that's the slow part, or your code to process it? How big is the data in each request? What's the network speed between the client and server? We can't say whether you're doing something "wrong", because we have no idea what your expectations are or whether they are realistic.

Comment: I realize that. I gave you link to the API so you can see the data size. Download speed can vary because it's a network in a dormitory. Do you see any flaws in the code?

Comment: With respect, you should include relevant info in the question, not expect people to derive it. What's the size of the data please? Is it the same for each of your 120 requests to it? You also still haven't told us how long it takes, or how long you expected it to take, or anything else I asked. There's nothing _obviously_ wrong with the code, it clearly works as such, but any potential (or otherwise) for optimising or rearranging it depends on the things you aren't telling us. Also, why do you need to request it 120 times?